# Cannot install psycopg2 in virtualenv but can install it outside it

Tags: django, pip, virtualenv, psycopg2, virtualenvwrapper

I could install psycopg2 using pip outside a virtualenv (first part of my copy-paste below), but not inside a virtualenv that i created using virtualenvwrapper-win

Full list of modules in my python and in the python inside virtualenv (name = venv) below in the code

> C:\Users\Som>pip freeze Django==1.6.4 Pygments==1.6 colorama==0.3.1
>   httpie==0.8.0 psycopg2==2.5.2 requests==2.3.0 south==0.8.4
>   virtualenv==1.9.1 virtualenvwrapper-win==1.1.5
>
> C:\Users\Som>workon env
>
> ```
> virtualenv "env" does not exist. Create it with "mkvirtualenv env"
> ```
>
> C:\Users\Som>lsvirtualenv
>
> dir /b /ad "C:\Users\Som\Envs"
>   ============================================================================== venv webfactionenv
>
> C:\Users\Som>workon venv (venv) C:\Users\Som>pip freeze Django==1.6.5
>   django-toolbelt==0.0.1
>
> (venv) C:\Users\Som>pip install psycopg2 Downloading/unpacking
>   psycopg2   Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2
>
> Installing collected packages: psycopg2   Running setup.py install for
>   psycopg2
>       building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
>       error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
>       Complete output from command C:\Users\Som\Envs\venv\Scripts\python.exe -c "i mport
>   setuptools;**file**='C:\Users\Som\Envs\venv\build\psycopg2\setup.py
>   ';exec(compile(open(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record
>   c:\users\som\appdata\local\temp\pip-aywkat-record\install-recor d.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers C:\Users\Som\Envs\ve nv\include\site\python2.7:
>       running install
>
> running build
>
> running build_py
>
> running build_ext
>
> building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
>
> error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
>
> ---------------------------------------- Command C:\Users\Som\Envs\venv\Scripts\python.exe -c "import
>   setuptools;**file**
>   ='C:\Users\Som\Envs\venv\build\psycopg2\setup.py';exec(compile(open(**fil
>   e**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record c:\users \som\appdata\local\temp\pip-aywkat-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-ex ternally-managed --install-headers C:\Users\Som\Envs\venv\include\site\python2.7  failed with error code
>   1 in C:\Users\Som\Envs\venv\build\psycopg2 Storing complete log in
>   C:\Users\Som\pip\pip.log

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks. However, I found out that installing the exe from this link in the method specify definitely solves the problem

http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/

Comment: I tried a million other answers, including [the one that @tutuca linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat). This was the only solution that **finally** worked. That stickpeople site was a godsend